# "Linker input file not found" warning

Tags: codeblocks

I am here with a newbie question. I have just installed codeblocks. When I tried to run a simple hello word, I had the warning of "Linker input file not found." How can I solve this problem? Thank you. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswKE.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the project?

Lets try to fix it:
Project->Properties->Build targets->Build target files -> Is main.cpp checked?

Have you tried a new project? Without modification?
Does the path to your project has special characters, like non English or spaces?

Have you tried a rebuild: Build->Rebuild?

Comment: Yes, main.c is checked. And I have tried a new project. No, it only has English characters. And I have attempted to build and rebuild. But unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: No. I have right clicked the project name and changed it's title name. But it didn't solve my problem unfortunately

Comment: Could you paste your Compiler's installation directory path?

Comment: Hey Lukas. Thank you for your help. After deleting and downloading couple of times it worked.